# PHP and Javascript error

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(){
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['tagname']))
    {
    ?>
        var t = <?php echo $_SESSION['tagname'] ?>;
        $('.tag span').html(t);
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    $('.tag').hide();
    <?php
    }
    ?>
});
</script>
```

Now the problem is, the variable 't' is not getting set.
If I write a static text inside that line of code, then my code works.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you remember to call `session_start()` ?

Comment: you're missing a semicolon after `echo $_SESSION['tagname']`. Does that fix it?

Comment: Semicolon is not the issue, the issue was String Value as mentioned by @drew010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `t` is a string value, then that should be a syntax error because you would be using a string outside quotes.

Try

```
var t = '<?php echo $_SESSION['tagname'] ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode as JSON before outputting text to be used as JavaScript literals.

```
var t = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['tagname']) ?>;
```

And of course, make sure that `$_SESSION['tagname']` actually contains something.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `t` variable contains a string, which should be enclosed in single or double quotes (in this case, double quotes, as you have single quotes inside the string so it doesn't mess up).

```
var t = "<?php echo $_SESSION['tagname'] ?>;";
```

And, it depends if "tagname" is a Javascript variable or not.